# #Openseadragon how to configure plugin?

Tags: openseadragon

[openseadragon-canvas-overlay] requires PaperJS (anonymous) @ openseadragon-paperjs-overlay.js:19 (anonymous) @ openseadragon-paperjs-overlay.js:115

**Already added screen in angular.cli**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved Order of script inclusion matters,

```
"node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.min.js",                       
"node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js",
"node_modules/openseadragon-annotations/dist/openseadragon-annotations.js",
"node_modules/openseadragon-paperjs-overlay/openseadragon-paperjs-overlay.js",
"node_modules/openseadragon-fabricjs-overlay/openseadragon-fabricjs-overlay.js"
```